# Can i create a sum using a key? Absence tracker

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I’ve been tasked with creating an absence tracker that will monitor holidays and sickness - I have created the basic layout and a key which determines holiday = H half day morning =Hd1 absence = A etc ...
So the premise is obviously if employee 1 is on holiday you would enter H in the relevant date cell, off sock you would enter A.

What I’m struggling with is the correct formula to add them up each month so absence will be separate and not so much of an issue, but say they have Monday on holiday, and Tuesday as a morning on holiday and then they’re off on compassionate leave on Friday at the end of the month there would be 3 days authorised leave, I’m confused how I put that in a formula.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet and what have you tried so far? What formula are you using?

Comment: I think you should countif formula that counts your keys for each employee,

Comment: It won’t let me add a photo :(  I’m trying to break it down per month so it’s easy to manage as in reality this will house the attendance for a few hundred employees, but I need to see quickly employee 1 has had 3.5 days holiday in April but also had 2 days sick and then when I click into detail I can gain understanding of what days they are - the absence section is easy as it’s a simple count of the “a” but the counting and adding of the other letters is making it difficult for me.

Comment: You don't have to add a photo of it, you can create a copy of the sheet and use dummy data and then share the link with public access.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using countif formula:

```
=countif(D$6:D$34,$C2)
```

[image]

My solution is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_oCCsuvseJUqrjWgjDKesON9CSFLZTXxQvYAG8T5Cwk/copy